# ServiceStack doesn't populate error responses

Tags: servicestack

We're working on a project using ServiceStack (loving it) but need some help with a strange problem. In our project we throw or return various types of HttpError with ErrorResponse and ResponseStatus objects using a helper method.

It follows the pattern described [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#httperror-with-a-custom-response-dto). Something like this:

```
protected HttpError BusinessError(string summaryMessage = "Some generic validation summary.")
    {           
        return new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "MyValidationType", summaryMessage)
        {                           
            Response = new ErrorResponse
            {
                ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus
                {
                    ErrorCode = "MyValidationType",
                    Message = summaryMessage,
                    Errors = new List<ResponseError>()
                },
            }
        };
    }
```

In a service call we would use it like so:

```
throw BusinessError("Help I've fallen and can't get up!");
```

This would work a treat, and we'd feed it in to the ss-validation JS library to render our validation messages. Worked fine.

The problem is that now ServiceStack won't serialize any of the HttpError's details into the response. All we get is a response with the 400 status code, the 'MyValidationType' error code, and empty JSON response `{}`.

I've tried playing with combinations of throwing/returning the error and switching the service method's return type to `object` etc, but nothing seems to make a difference. To be honest I'm not sure what we could have changed in our project to cause this behavior.

I'd appreciate any advice or pointers as to what could cause this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if you're using a `{RequestName}` and `{RequestName}Response` naming convention and the [Response DTO does not have a ResponseStatus property](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#error-response-types):

> The {RequestDto}Response is returned, regardless of the service method's response type. If the {RequestDto}Response DTO **has a ResponseStatus property**, it is populated otherwise **no ResponseStatus will be returned**. (If you have decorated the {ResponseDto}Response class and properties with [DataContract]/[DataMember] attributes, then ResponseStatus also needs to be decorated, to get populated).

In which case the solution is just to add a ResponseStatus property to the Response DTO:

```
public class RequestNameResponse
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be our case exactly.  I'm curious though, what's the reason behind this requirement? It seems like a restriction to me, since there's a whole range of options available for throwing/returning custom errors and responses and this just seems to couple it to our Response DTO. In my way of thinking, our {RequestName}Respones DTO represents a successful response - everything else that is a deviation from this should be handled by SS's exception/validation/custom errors framework, keeping our DTOs clean.

Comment: @Martaver The RequestResponse convention is a way to associate a Response DTO with a Request DTO, it allows typed clients to always predict what the Response Type for a Request should be whether or not it failed. It also allows servers to control whether or not the particular Service should return a populated ResponseStatus with error information or not.

Comment: Okay, I get the benefit in that but sometimes we use that pattern and other times we don't - it might be appropriate to just return a collection of entity DTOs or a single entity DTO directly... this is in line with the idea of 'pure responses' outlined in your description of the 'less restrictive new API': https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API... In those cases, ServiceStack handles the thrown HttpError fine and we don't have to put a ResponseStatus property on our entity DTOs. Why should we for the RequestResponse DTOs? Or should we be using RequestResponse everywhere?

Comment: @Martaver If you do use the RequestResponse pattern then you'd just need to add the ResponseStatus property. I personally use explicit Response DTO's so I can later modify the response to return extra data/metadata without breaking clients, also there's a security risk if your [Service returns a JSON Array](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/) which is another reason I avoid it. Ultimately its up to you what you choose to do, you'd just need to remember if you use the RequestResponse convention, the Response DTO is always going to get returned from that Service.

Comment: Thanks mythz, that's great to know! Appreciate the clarification.